# Custom badge layout on navigation drawer is not showing correctly

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am working on an application, in which i am using custom badge layout for navigation drawer badge. But these counts are not showing correctly:
[image]
**menu_counter.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_outline">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counterView"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

In **MainActivity.xml**

```
countSideMenu = (TextView) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.count).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.counterView);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Replace this code with your framlayout

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_outline">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counterView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/red_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have already accepted it, but i think its not visible. BTW thanks